# How could I use the Curve 25519 with gpg2 under 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, gnupg, 18.04, libgcrypt

I want to use the elliptic curve 25519 with `gpg2`.

I use gpg2 2.1.11. I read that it could use the Curve25519. But I couldn't choose it.
I think the problem is, that my gpg2 uses the older version of `libgcrypt` 1.6.5. But I also installed `libgcrypt20`.

How could I link gpg2 with the newer version or do I have to build it?

Other idea: is it better to wait for ubuntu 18.04 where I get better support for elliptic curves?

Thanks for help.